# Magento error There has been an error processing your request

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.3

```
Error in file: "/var/www/html/magento_1.3.2.4/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.7.39-0.7.40.php" - Unknown error (8192): Function split() is deprecated  in /var/www/html/magento_1.3.2.4/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.7.39-0.7.40.php on line 35
```

Trace:

```
#0 /var/www/html/magento_1.3.2.4/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(292): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /var/www/html/magento_1.3.2.4/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(168): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '0.7.0', '0.7.69')
#2 /var/www/html/magento_1.3.2.4/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(155): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('0.7.69')
#3 /var/www/html/magento_1.3.2.4/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(121): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /var/www/html/magento_1.3.2.4/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(263): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /var/www/html/magento_1.3.2.4/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(263): Mage_Core_Model_Config->init(Array)
#6 /var/www/html/magento_1.3.2.4/app/Mage.php(434): Mage_Core_Model_App->init('', 'store', Array)
#7 /var/www/html/magento_1.3.2.4/app/Mage.php(455): Mage::app('', 'store', Array)
#8 /var/www/html/magento_1.3.2.4/index.php(65): Mage::run()
#9 {main}
```

Comment: Replace the split with an http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

You are using upper version of PHP and Lower version of Magento. That's why this error is throwing. Either upgrade magento or degrade PHP version on your server.

Helpful link: http://www.geekieblog.com/2011/03/magento-1-3-x-environment-won%E2%80%99t-run-on-php-5-3/